# Hbs convert to Jade, Express framework

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I was writing this for the express Hbs engine, but I would like to convert it to Jade. This piece of code worked on another one of my works, but I need to have it in Jade, I have problems with the handlerbars.

```js
{{# each products}}
    <div class="row">
        {{#each this}}
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="{{this.imagePath}}" title="ImagePreview" alt="My shopping car">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>{{this.title}}</h3>
                        <p>{{this.description}}</p>
                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <div class="price pull-left">{{this.price}}</div>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success pull-right" role="button">Add to car</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pug 2 syntax:

```
each productRow in products
  .row: each product in productRow
    .col-sm-6.col-md-4: .thumbnail
      img(src=product.imagePath title="ImagePreview" alt="My shopping car")
      .caption
        h3=product.title
        p=product.description
        .clearfix
          .price.pull-left=product.price
          a(href="#" class="btn btn-success pull-right" role="button") Add to car
```

Add a `-` before each and `,` between attributes for old pug versions.